# Why does this image not appear in the browser even after the state being loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to render a profile picture with an "src" link provided by the Twitch API. What I expected to happen was that the image renders correctly after the brief "Loading..." message, What I got was the loading message appearing for a brief second but after that there was no image, according to the browser all that got rendered was a `<img>` with no src.

I am pretty new to React and Next and after a day troubleshooting I still do not know why this doesn't work. I have read the docs pretty thoroughly and browsed through countless questions here and I still can't figure out what's wrong

This is the component:

```jsx
export class twitchInfoCard extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFetching: true,
            pfp: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, isFetching: true });
        twitchApi.userQ('insomniac').then(r => {
            r = r.json().then(result => {
                this.setState({ pfp: result.data[0].thumbnail_url, isFetching: false });
                console.log(result.data[0])
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="profile-info rounded-md flex">
                {this.state.isFetching ? 'Loading' : <img src={this.state.pfp} />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the API response:

```json
{
  "id": "232672264",
  "login": "insomniac",
  "display_name": "Insomniac",
  "type": "",
  "broadcaster_type": "partner",
  "description": "Wide Awake Since '93",
  "profile_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/be6b7ece-3c44-4100-8744-3578d112c862-profile_image-300x300.png",
  "offline_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/91e4f13e-ffcb-4889-8632-5df9392181d0-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
  "view_count": 152550798,
  "created_at": "2018-06-19T20:47:21.29642Z"
}
```

Comment: There is no thumbnail_url in the api response you shared and you're assigning that to the state.

Comment: @Junaid thank you so much, after so much time looking at the same screen with nothing working I guess I just missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API response, I dont see any name with **thumbnail_url**, If you want to render image, you may setState the pfp to **profile_image_url** or **offline_image_url** once the fetching is successful.